# Nativescript - is it possible to text/sms an image?

Tags: nativescript

In my app, sometimes I'd like user to be able to text an image?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you're looking for, there's a plugin available for sharing text and images from your app with the native sharing widget of Android/iOS: https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-social-share